# Device Provisioning via Enrollment group

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-sdk, azure-iot-dps

Azure C SDK supports connecting device to the Device Provisioning Service via Enrollment group ?

Developing for FreeRTOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes!

The device doesn't know anything about enrollment groups - the device sends its registration Id and authentication data to DPS. DPS figures out which allocation group or individual enrollment to use.

- For more info, see
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps
- For C DPS registration samples, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/main/provisioning_client/samples

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is support for the FreeRTOS device? I found an issue on GitHub, see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/issues/225

Answer (score 0):

group enrollment is supported by C SDK.

You can leverage this MSFT doc as reference for [provisioning X.509 devices using enrollment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509?tabs=windows&source=docs).

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is support for the FreeRTOS device? I found an issue on GitHub, see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/issues/225